# hashcode and equals rewrite not working, what is wrong

Tags: java

I am using coder pad to do this, and it seems that the results shows me duplicates even after rewrite hashCode and equals. Appreciate your help!

```
   public static class Point{//just a class
       int x, y;
       Point(int x, int y){
         this.x = x;
         this.y = y;
       }
     // @Override
       public int hashCode(){//17 and 31 from effective java
            int result = 17;
            result = 31 * result + x;
            result = 31 * result + y;
           return result;
       }
    //  @Override
       public boolean equals(Point p){
          return p.x == x && p.y == y;
       }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {//main func
    Set<Point> res = new HashSet<>();
    res.add(new Point(100, 0));
    res.add(new Point(100, 0));
    for (Point a: res){   
      System.out.println(a.x + " " + a.y);
  }
```

Comment: If you uncomment the `// @Override` annotations in your code, the compiler will tell you that you are actually not overriding `equals`. That's because `equals` takes an `Object` as an argument, and not a `Point`.

Comment: And that is the entire point of using `@Override`.

Answer (score 7):

You haven't overridden equals, you overloaded equals, and that isn't going to do the job.

Your `equals` method *must* take an Object argument, and then cast as appropriate.  You must write something like

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
  if (o instanceof Point) {
    Point p = (Point) o;
    return x==p.x && y==p.y;
  }
  return false;
}
```